# Changing style of marker on hover and moving in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, angularjs

There are a some places marked on the map by click.

I need to add style when user hover the marker and when moving it.

I tried this way (using Selection object):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-openlayers-map-c3tcw1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Also I have tried to register event on feature as:

```
featureIcon.on("hover", (e) => { // chnage style })
```

Also I tried to attach `new Seelection()` to the concrete feature

Relevant code is:

```
  const selected_feature = new Select({
      condition: pointerMove,
      style: new Style({
        image: new Icon(
          /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            scale: 2,
          })
        ),
      }),
    });

    map.addInteraction(selected_feature);
```

The rest part of code by [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-openlayers-map-c3tcw1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Done, you can check it by link

Comment: `Icon` style needs a `src` to be specified

Comment: I already have it in source code. Check it out please by link

Comment: The only option you had for the Select style was scale.  If you want to scale up the existing icon you must repeat all the other options https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-openlayers-map-o2k5jo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: How to avoid this duplication of code? I What if I create a feature icon dinamically?

Comment: You could use style functions and set the scale of the icon to 1 or 2 as required https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-openlayers-map-hvduaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts